# How to set the resty.core dir in Kong?

Tags: nginx, kong, openresty

nginx: 1.19  openresty: 1.19

I have installed `Kong` with `--prefix=/home/mykong`, it is installed in custom directory `/home/mykong`. And it created `etc` `usr/local` `lib` automatically under `/home/mykong`, so the dir is like this

```
/home/mykong
----usr/local
----etc/kong
----lib
```

I start `Kong` under my dir, `./usr/local/bin/kong  start -c etc/kong/kong.conf`.
I got this:

```
nginx: [alert] failed to load the 'resty.core' module (https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core); ensure you are using an OpenResty release from https://openresty.org/en/download.html (reason: module 'resty.core' not found:
    no field package.preload['resty.core']
    no file '/usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/resty/core.ljbc'
    no file '/usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/resty/core/init.ljbc'
    no file '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/resty/core.ljbc'
    no file '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/resty/core/init.ljbc'
    no file '/usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/resty/core.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/resty/core/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/resty/core.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/resty/core/init.lua'
    no file './resty/core.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/openresty/luajit/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta3/resty/core.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/resty/core.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/resty/core/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/openresty/luajit/share/lua/5.1/resty/core.lua'
    no file '/usr in /tmp/resty_IKDrdnjeHs/conf/nginx.conf:62
```

But `resty.core` is in `/home/mykong/usr/local/openresty/lualib/resty/`, so how to set the path for `openresty` to find `resty.core`?